# Horizontally Tile Div Tags with Bootstrap and maximize on click

Tags: html, angularjs, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using angular JS and Bootstrap to display some dynamic data, I currently have it tiling 3 divs. However I need it to tile more than 3 i need them to be smaller, however I can't figure out the bottstrap if i use the smaller column size it just puts one or 2 per row. I need at least 7 per row. Also my function to have them maximize on click isnt working either and i dont know why..

This is what im at now it all works except for setting the ngclick I get an error..

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Relic</title>

    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.scrolly.min.js"></script>
    <link href="css/cover.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/social.js"></script> 
    <script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
         $('.hide_div').hide();

            $('.show_button').click(function(){

                /**
                 * when show button is clicked we call the show plugin
                 * which scales the box to default size
                 * You can try other effects from here: http://jqueryui.com/effect/
                 */
                $(".hide_div").show("scale", 500); 

            });

            $('.show_button').click(function(){

                //same thing happens except in this case we hide the element
                $(".hide_div").hide("scale", 500); 

            });
        });

    </script>


    </head>

    <body ng-app="userProfile" ng-controller="ProfileController as post" >


    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </div>

        <div class="container-fluid" id="content">  
          <div class="row" >    
                    <ul ng-repeat="post in post.userPost" class="col-md-1" id="post">
                    <li ng-click='tab = {{post.message}}' class='show_button'>{{post.title}}{{post.message}}</li>
                    </ul>

                    </div>
                </div>
           </div>           
        </div>  
<div id='fullscreen' class='hide_div'>{{tab}}
    <div class='show_button'>test</div></div>



</body>

</html>
```

this is the error im getting

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'post.message' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 9 of the expression [tab = {{post.message}}] starting at [post.message}}].
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.17/$parse/syntax?p0=post.message&p1=is%20unexpected%2C%20expecting%20%5B%3A%5D&p2=9&p3=tab%20%3D%20%7B%7Bpost.message%7D%7D&p4=post.message%7D%7D
    at file:///C:/Users/TheLastOne/Desktop/Angular/js/angular.js:78:12
    at Parser.throwError (file:///C:/Users/TheLastOne/Desktop/Angular/js/angular.js:10739:11)
    at Parser.consume (file:///C:/Users/TheLastOne/Desktop/Angular/js/angular.js:10773:12)
    at Parser.object (file:///C:/Users/TheLastOne/Desktop/Angular/js/angular.js:11075:14)
    at Parser.primary (file:///C:/Users/TheLastOne/Desktop/Angular/js/angular.js:10707:22)
    at Parser.unary (file:///C:/Users/TheLastOne/Desktop/Angular/js/angular.js:10958:19)
    at Parser.multiplicative (file:///C:/Users/TheLastOne/Desktop/Angular/js/angular.js:10941:21)
    at Parser.additive (file:///C:/Users/TheLastOne/Desktop/Angular/js/angular.js:10932:21)
    at Parser.relational (file:///C:/Users/TheLastOne/Desktop/Angular/js/angular.js:10923:21)
    at Parser.equality (file:///C:/Users/TheLastOne/Desktop/Angular/js/angular.js:10914:21) <li ng-click="tab = {{post.message}}" class="show_button">
```

Comment: Where to begin, - 1) Your bootstrap grid is based on 12 columns so col-xs-6 will be 2 columns, 7? would be odd, but 6 would be col-xs-2 -- 2) You don't use an id with a repeat, you use a class. This could explain your little jquery there.

Comment: well when you click the div post any div with the id post, it will make that div full screen. I'm gonna write a close as well but i want this to work first. I'm trying to do a css based tile site, thats dynamic.

Comment: when you click whatever id = post its supposed to change the width of that element and height.

Answer (score 0):

An `id` needs to be unique, so what you want to use inside any loop or repeat is a `class`, so `class="post"` and `$('.post').click(..)`.

Either that or you can have a big mess of indexed ids like `id="post{{$index}}"` `id="fullscreen{{$index}}"` but that doesn't sound fun.

It would also make alot more sense in this case to use ng-click.

Here is a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gVZ1bOkf9EOQQTooSE3g?p=preview)

Comment: oh thank you so much i'm just learning angular js and javascript from my normal python is a bit tricky. Thanks so much i will try that @Dylan. I will let you know.